# Why does the previous image draw on my HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

this code draws an image of the user's local computer on a canvas then slide it on some other canvases for slide puzzle game

```
function drawImage(event) {

        if (event.target.files.length <= 0) return;
        var files = event.target.files;
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var img = $("#image")[0];

        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);

        getCanvas("karajan").drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, 450, 450);

       ...........

    }

    function getCanvas(id) {
        var canvas = $("#" + id)[0];
        if (canvas.getContext) {
            return canvas.getContext("2d");
        }
        return undefined;
    }
```

and a tag that inputs image file from local computer

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image_input" onchange="drawImage(event)"/>
<img id="image"/>
```

and when user want to change the image, the canvas will draw with previous image. I don't know why. in the first lines of drawImage function image changes with newer image and draws on canvas

Comment: You might have to wait until the image is loaded, even if it is a data URL.

Comment: @FelixKling Erm... `data` URLs do not load, they just are.

Comment: @Kolink: I know... still, it does not mean that the browser instantly draws or sets the image. It might do it *after* the current script terminates.

Comment: More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images. You can also see that they release the URL object thingy inside the `load` event handler. You should probably draw your image there.

Comment: @FelixKling You say that I should add something like setTimeout in my function?

Comment: No, you should bind an event handler to the load event: `img.onload = function() { /* do something */ };`.

Comment: @FelixKling it works, thank bro. write your comment as answer

Comment: @FelixKling Ich danke dich bruder :D

Comment: @Pooya: "Ich danke dir" ... good though :)

Comment: @FelixKling Why dir? why not dich? dir is Dativ and dich is accusative. and I thought that dich is Correct

Comment: Yep and dative is correct here, not accusative. Why? Because that's how it is ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the image is not actually "loaded" until the current script terminates. That means you should listen to the load event of the image and only then draw it to the canvas.

I did some restructuring of your code as well. If you already have jQuery available, use it:

```
$(function() {
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var $image = $('#image').on('load', function() {
        // clear canvas here
        getCanvas("karajan")
            .drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height, 0, 0, 450, 450);
        // ...
    });

    $('#image_input').on('change', function() {
        if (this.files.length === 0) return;

        $image.prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
    });
});
```

You should still clear the canvas though, as Kolink suggested. Otherwise, if a new, smaller image is loaded, parts of the previous, larger image will still be visible.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas does not clear itself, you have to tell it to clear. You can either wipe the whole thing with, or a controlled area, using `clearRect(x,y,w,h)`. After this, you can draw the new image.

Comment: Thanks Kolink, but still I have this problem after added `canvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` before the drawImage

Comment: `clearRect` is a method of the drawing context, but `width` and `height` are properties of the canvas. You can't have both of them in the same `canvas` variable.